# Creating an unordered list through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a div using javascript in another function and I have styled it in the function I am about to show (this is all working) I am attempting to fill the div with an unordered list, this is what I have so far:

```
function LeftSideMenu() {
// getting the javascript named div
var x = document.getElementById("sideMenu");

// Styling the div
x.style.width = "300px";
x.style.height = "750px";
x.style.position = "absolute";
x.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
x.style.border = "thick solid #901709";
x.style.borderWidth = "10px";
x.style.background = "#c01e0c";

var sideList = ['About', 'Players', 'Achievements']
var unorderedList = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < sideList.Length; i++) {

    // Create a new 'LI' element for each part of the sideList array
    var theList = document.createElement('li');

    // Set the contents of the list seen in "sideList"
    theList.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sideList[i]));

    // Appened the list to the unorderedList
    unorderedList.appendChild(theList);
}

// Return the occupied list
return unorderedList;
}
```

So the question is, how do I fill the list with the 'sideList' contents and put that list into my 'sideMenu' (AKA var = x) div. I would also like to avoid JQuery if possible.

Comment: The only thing you haven't done is to insert the `ul` into the `sideMenu` div.

Comment: ^^ that and `sideList.Length` should be `sideList.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done almost all of it right, except that:

1. You need to append `unorderedList` somewhere in the DOM for it to show up on the page. If you wnt it to be in `sideMenu`, then at the end:

   ```
   x.appendChild(unorderedList);
   ```
2. You've used `sideList.Length` instead of `sideList.length` (lower case `l` on `length`). Case matters in JavaScript.

Example:

```js
function LeftSideMenu() {
  // getting the javascript named div
  var x = document.getElementById("sideMenu");

  // Styling the div
  x.style.width = "300px";
  x.style.height = "750px";
  x.style.position = "absolute";
  x.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
  x.style.border = "thick solid #901709";
  x.style.borderWidth = "10px";
  x.style.background = "#c01e0c";

  var sideList = ['About', 'Players', 'Achievements']
  var unorderedList = document.createElement('ul');

  for (var i = 0; i < sideList.length; i++) {

    // Create a new 'LI' element for each part of the sideList array
    var theList = document.createElement('li');

    // Set the contents of the list seen in "sideList"
    theList.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sideList[i]));

    // Appened the list to the unorderedList
    unorderedList.appendChild(theList);
  }

  // Append the list to the menu div            ***
  x.appendChild(unorderedList);              // ***
  
  // Return the occupied list
  return unorderedList;
}

LeftSideMenu();
```

```html
<div id="sideMenu"></div>
```

Comment: return unorderedList;
x.appendChild(makeUL(sideList[0]));
}

Like that?

Comment: @JoeG: No, `return` exits the function immediately, so statements after it don't get run. Either append it *before* the `return`, or do it outside the function using the return value of the function. Note: I added a live example above (and found a second error while doing so).

Answer (score 1):

you are only missing

```
x.appendChild(unorderedList);
```

before the `return unorderedList;`.

Answer (score 0):

add `x.appendChild(unorderedList);` and in `sideList.Length` `l` should be small case

```js
function LeftSideMenu() {
// getting the javascript named div
var x = document.getElementById("sideMenu");

// Styling the div
x.style.width = "300px";
x.style.height = "750px";
x.style.position = "absolute";
x.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
x.style.border = "thick solid #901709";
x.style.borderWidth = "10px";
x.style.background = "#c01e0c";

var sideList = ['About', 'Players', 'Achievements'];
var unorderedList = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < sideList.length; i++) {
  // Create a new 'LI' element for each part of the sideList array
    var theList = document.createElement('li');

    // Set the contents of the list seen in "sideList"
    theList.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sideList[i]));

    // Appened the list to the unorderedList
    unorderedList.appendChild(theList);
}

// Return the occupied list
  x.appendChild(unorderedList);
return;
}
window.onload=function(){
  LeftSideMenu();
}
```

```html
<div id="sideMenu"></div>
```